# How to remove Headline from Joomla

Tags: joomla

I use Joomla version 1.7, and header of pages have captions "Headline" and "Slogan text". I can't find how can I delete or fix it. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can remove it (set it to blank), although doing so is generally not something you would want to do (`<title>` is a required element in most HTML schemas for a reason).

However, you can easily change what appears there. There are two levels at which you can do this:

**Menu Item**

If a page is a menu item, you can change the page title by going into the Menu Manager for the appropriate item, then editing the item. By default the 'Menu Title' is also used as the page title, however you may want the page title and menu title to differ. If that's the case, expand 'Page Display Options' in the right sidebar, and edit 'Browser Page Title'.

**Article**

If a page is an article (and this may apply with some other types of content in Joomla as well, depending on how they're set up), then you can change the page title by going into the Article Manager for the appropriate article, then editing the article. The page title is the main 'Title' attribute (first on the page).